# im trying to convert my .py app into executeable file with pyinstall but im facing this error:

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
raise ImportError("No module named " + target_package_name)
ImportError: No module named _bootlocale
```

I tried to run `pyinstaller Gunshop.py --exclude-module _bootlocale` command
and now im getting this :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: What python version and OS are you using?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.